# How to clear run anything history commands in Android Studio 3.4?

Tags: android-studio

I tried looking in the Settings, but couldn't find a button to clear the history.
Is there a command that can be used to clear commands that have been entered?
[image: Run Anything dialog in Android Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the up/down arrows to select the command that you to delete
2. press shift+backspace to delete it

Poof - its gone

Comment: Hi, If my answer helped you please accept it as an answer so it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 3.4 but in a recent version, I found the terminal history under `~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio{VVVV.V}/terminal/history`

(...where `~` refers to the user home directory in Linux/Mac)